# Listing only working directory files and dirs in hg manifest?

Tags: mercurial

I'm trying to get a list of the current files and dirs using the following command:

```
hg manifest -r tip
```

However, this brings a list like this:

```
.hgtags
folder1/blah.c
folder1/blah.h
foo.json
folder2/bleh.c
folder2/bleh.h
test.json
```

How can I list only the following?

```
.hgtags
folder1
foo.json
folder2
test.json
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Unix machine you could try:

```
hg manifest -r tip | cut -d "/" -f 1 | sort -u
```

or

```
hg manifest -r tip | cut -d "/" -f 1 | uniq
```

1. `cut -d "/" -f 1`: select first portion delimited by '/'
2. `uniq`: filter out repeated lines

Or using Python (more cross-platform):

You need to have python-glib installed (via pip)

```
import hglib
repo = hglib.open("/path/to/repo")
manifest = repo.manifest("tip")
files = set(f[4].split('/')[0] for f in manifest)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I was looking for a cross-platform solution. :(

Answer (score 0):

A Mercurial-only command for listing files in the pwd that are under version control is:

```
hg files "glob:*"
```

Since both the `manifest` and `files` commands are file-oriented, it may simply not be possible to achieve the stated goal using a Mercurial-only approach.